# Rtsne: Perplexity is too large

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to use tSNE on a gene expression matrix that has the following dimensions: 7x5000. I have removed low variance, low expression and duplicated values:

```
     ENSMUSG00000022037 ENSMUSG00000064351 ENSMUSG00000047517 ENSMUSG00000101111
852_1           18.04494           16.58238          14.760356           14.72078
852_2           18.33979           16.08849          15.846886           14.13721
852_3           17.27803           16.63105          13.483438           14.78686
852_4           18.08123           16.17240          13.854479           13.97815
853_1           15.87570           16.43745          10.016808           14.47457
853_2           14.13963           18.19087           8.654636           16.73305
853_3           17.95099           16.66351          17.109841           14.49093
```

Here is how I run tSNE:

```
tsne_out <- Rtsne(mat, dims = 3)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Error in Rtsne.default(unique(t(highly_variable)), dims = 3) : 
  Perplexity is too large.
```

Can someone advise on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason why you're getting this error is: This function has a `perplexity` of 30 by default. And your data has just 7 records. Try using `tsne_out <- Rtsne(as.matrix(mat), dims = 3, perplexity = 1) `. It should work.

Comment: @samadhi Is it recommended to change the perplexity parameter?

Comment: I guess you should try different values of perplexity which could be ideally between 5 to 50 to get an optimized value for t-SNE . Have a look at this article https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 2 years late, but after reading the @sm925's comment I went and checked the documentation (`?Rtsne`) and found:

> ```
> perplexity    numeric; Perplexity parameter (should not be bigger
>               than 3 * perplexity < nrow(X) - 1, see details for
>               interpretation)
> ```

So basically we can reverse-calculate the highest acceptable perplexity:

```r
my_Rtsne <- Rtsne(X = data.matrix(data),
                  perplexity = floor((nrow(data) - 1) / 3),
                  dims = 2)
```

Comment: I get the error that the perplexity should be a positive number

Comment: @Ben What does the `nrow(data)` return? Because the `floor((nrow(data) - 1) / 3)` can get negative if an only if when `nrow(data) < 1`

Comment: True, I had some issues in my data. Works now, thanks!